# Subquery in UNION select not preserving order

Tags: sql-server

I'm selecting from 3 different tables using `UNION`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT car AS searchword, 0 AS priority FROM Cars
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT animal AS searchword, 1 AS priority FROM Animals WHERE animal <> 'dog'
UNION 
SELECT color AS searchword, 2 AS priority FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT color FROM Colors ORDER BY [count] DESC) as a
ORDER BY priority ASC
```

However when I run this, the following `SELECT` doesn't preserve its order:

```
SELECT color AS searchword, 2 AS priority FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT color FROM Colors ORDER BY [count] DESC) as a
```

What's a way around this? I need a result set in this order:  `Cars`,`Animals`,`Colors`, I can't intermix the SELECTS. And `Colors` needs to be ordered through the `count` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second code block, your ORDER BY clause is inside your subquery.  Once you leave the subquery and move to the outer query, there is no ORDER BY clause.  So there is no guarantee for order.

In your first code block, there is in fact an ORDER BY clause, so you are guaranteed an order in that case, but it is on 'priority'.

If you're looking to order by 'priority', then by the 'count' in the subquery, you'll have to find a way to get the 'count' as part of the outer query:

```
select    searchword = car, 
          priority = 0, 
          [count] = null 
from      Cars

union 
select    animal, 1, null
from      Animals 
where     animal <> 'dog'

union 
select    color, 2, [count]
from      colors 

order by  priority ASC, count desc
```

In this case, the refactoring eliminates the need for the subquery altogether.

By the way, I got rid of some unnecessary distincts (union already does distinct).